# Automorphisms of $\mathbb{C}$ are bounded on balls.

Tags: complex-numbers

In the context of Algebraicity of the Gauss-Manin connection, it seems to me that they are assuming the following fact.

Let $\varphi$ be an automorphism of $\mathbb{C}$ as a field, not necessarily continuous. Then there is a complex disk $S=\{z\in \mathbb{C}:\left| z \right| <\varepsilon\}$, with $\varepsilon$ small enough, such that $\varphi(S)$ is contained in a disk.

How can I prove this fact? Am I misinterpreting the situation and actually there are counterexamples?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this boundedness claim is false, unless of course $\varphi$ happens to be continuous.  To see why, notice first that, being a field automorphism, $\varphi$ must map all rational numbers to themselves, and therefore in particular, for any complex number $z$ and any positive integer $N$, we have $\varphi(z/N)=\varphi(z)/N$.  Therefore, if $\varphi$ maps the disk (by which I mean disk centered at $0$) of radius $\varepsilon$ into a big disk of radius $R$, then it maps the disk of radius $\varepsilon/N$ into a disk of radius $R/N$.  By taking $N$ large enough compared to $R$, this shows that $\varphi$ is continuous at $0$. Since it respects addition, $\varphi$ is continuous everywhere.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Actually one can show something more, the only continuous automorphisms of $\mathbb{C}$ are the identity and complex conjugation (http://math.ucr.edu/~res/progeom/oldversions/pgnotesappd.pdf).
Can you argument a bit more on your feeling of the claim being false?

Comment: I don't understand what sort of additional argument you might want. My answer already proves that the claim is false whenever $\varphi$ isn't continuous.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood your argument.